# Reject Documentation Topic Creation with barely any Content

Tags: discussion, documentation, proposed-changes

When browsing the "Documentation: Proposed Changes" review queue I came across a topic creation that featured barely any content. 2 sentences for the introduction and 1 line of code in the example. Although everything seemed correct I did not know what to do.

I actually wanted to reject it but for what reason? So I just skipped it instead. What should I do in that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **"Not documentation"** reason:

> *Does not attempt to explain or illustrate the topic*. It may be a request for improvement, a question, or something else unrelated to Documentation.

(Emphasis mine)